# How to limit power consumption to a certain value?

Tags: power, current, power-electronics, power-consumption, aviation-electronics

For the SAE Aerodesign competition, there is a requirement to create an electric RC airplane that does not exceed 750 W of power consumption at any time.
The electrical circuit consists of a 22.2 V (nominal voltage) Li-ion battery connected to an ESC (DC motor speed controller) to power and control the brushless motor and also connected to a device called a BEC ([Battery Eliminator Circuit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battery_eliminator_circuit)) which is basically a step-down regulator to 5 V to power the receiver and servos.

I would like to know how I can create a circuit that does not allow consuming more than 750 W at any time during the flight

Comment: step one would be to find out how the power consumption will be measured

Comment: I forgot to mention but there is also a wattmeter connected that record and store Wp (highest value of power during each flight)

Comment: You could make a current limit circuit with a shunt, an op amp and a mosfet. Set the limit to 33A. This method is not very accurate but it’s easy to make

Comment: If you have a fancy enough ESC it will have this option built in.

Comment: You can enhance the solution from @Panthera by increasing the current limit reference as the battery voltage decreases over time.

Answer (score 2):

It's not straight forward. You will need to measure the battery voltage and the battery current, multiply the two to get the power, compare that to 750 W, feed that into a servo loop, whose output overrides the speed control input to the Electronic Speed Control (ESC). You can to all that with the a microcontroller with A/D inputs and a PWM output.

Answer (score 0):

It's not enough to *do it*.  You also need to *prove it*.

So you shouldn't be asking us how to *do it*.

You should be asking your sanctioning agency what their criteria are  so that your airplane is "inspectable" to affirm it meets the requirements.   *That will generally inform (or force) your design.*